# Spring Boot way of implementing the command HTTP OPTIONS with credentials in header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-options-method

I am new to the Spring Boot, but I have worked with Java before on HTTP OPTIONS command.

I am building a service method that takes in an URL and test that URL using HTTP OPTIONS command.

Below is what I have written using Java:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

    ...

public String testConnection(URL url) {
    try {
              String type = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
              HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

              conn.setDoOutput(true);
              conn.setRequestMethod("OPTIONS");
              conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", type);

              System.out.println(String.format("HTTP %d: %s",
                    conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage()));

              for(String header : conn.getHeaderFields().keySet() ){
                 System.out.println(String.format("%s : %s",
                       header, conn.getHeaderFields().get(header)));
              }

              String rMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
              System.out.println ("Response " + rMessage);

           } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
}
```

Is there a Spring Boot equivalent way of implementing the HTTP OPTIONS request?  If so, could I also add credentials (username and password) to the header as part of the request?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Spring Boot's `RestTemplate`:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

// skipping class definition here, just showing the method call

private void optionsCall() {
    final String url = "https://some.server/with/some/path";
    final String user = "theUser";
    final String password = "thePassword";

    final String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder()
            .encodeToString((user + ':' + password).getBytes());

    final HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.set("Authorization", authHeaderValue);

    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    final ResponseEntity<Object> optionsResponse =
            rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.OPTIONS,
                    new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders),
                    Object.class);

    optionsResponse.getHeaders().forEach((key, value) -> log.info("{} -> {}", key, value));
}
```

I use an `Object` here for the response body type, normally an OPTION request does not return something, but it is not forbidden to do so, and the `exchange` method wants to have a class there. I log the returned headers using an slf4j Logger. Tested against a service using https and basic authentication.